# How to select elements that are in ajax response after validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

I'm using ajax to send data from my form. I'm using Laravel, in controller I'm using Validator and I return json when there are validation errors like that:

```html
$messages = $this->getValidation('individual', $input, 0);

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Response::json(array(
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()

    ));
}
```

In my view I show only part of code that is needed:

```html
$.ajax({
  url: form.action,
  type: form.method,
  data: $(form).serialize(),
  success: function(response) {                 

    $.each(response.errors, function (key, value) {

      $('input[name=key]').addClass('error'); //I can't get input with the same name as the key

    }}";

});
```

I want if there is error property in json, to select input, select or textarea which name is the same as the key in $.each function and add them error class.

Returned data is in this format:

```html
{"success":false,"errors":{"title":["The title field is required."],"first_name":["The first name field
 is required."],"last_name":["The last name field is required."],"front_passport":["The front passport
 field is required."]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting elements with name `'key'`; replace your selector with:

```
 $('input[name='+key+']').addClass('error');
```

Comment: Oh, yes, I fixed it. And how should I select each element with this name, because element could be radio button or textarea? :)

Comment: $('[name="ElementNameHere"]')